# Weak center is same as center for $C^{\ast}$-Algebra?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be a $C^{\ast}$-algebra. We say $A$ is weakly commutative if $ab^*c=cb^*a$ for all $a,b,c \in A$ and define weak center of $A$ as $$Z_w(A)= \{ v \in A : av^*c=cv^*a \;\forall a,c \in A \}.$$

> Are these notions of weak commutativity and weak center the same as the usual notions of commutativity and center in $C^{\ast}$-algebras?

By using approximate identity, I have managed to prove that both notions weakly commutative and commutative are same. It is also clear that center of $A$, i.e., $Z(A)$, contains $Z_w(A)$ but reverse inclusion is not clear. Any ideas?

Comment: By the way the star sign on $b$ and $v$ is redundant (by the obvious change of variable $b\mapsto b^*$). In particular, the definition doesn't involve the star map. My opinion in this case is that the question should be amended (despite already having an answer, which could be a comment) to make it non-trivial (currently it's clearly not research-level, namely not seriously thought).

Comment: @YCor: I asked this question as I was trying to figure out definition of center of TRO. Please see my comment below.

Comment: Yes but asking a question about $C^*$-algebras to which $M_2(\mathbf{C})$ is a trivial counterexample is not serious (and actually every non-abelian unital $C^*$-algebra is a trivial counterexample, for the same reason). I'd have recommended to delete it, but unfortunately this is not possible now it has an answer.

Comment: @YCor: I agree, please accept my sincere apologies.

Comment: You don't have to, I'm not offended.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question for the reasons mentioned by @YCor

Comment: Add to the closing reasons that the question was also asked [verbatim](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3717726/22857) in MSE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the same. The center of $M_2$ is $\mathbb{C}\cdot I_2$, but its weak center is $\{0\}$. E.g. $I_2$ is not in the weak center because not all $a,c \in M_2$ commute.

Comment: Thank you.  Actually I was trying to define Center for TRO and this definition what I called weak center was suggested here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/362862/definition-of-center-of-ternary-ring-of-operators. Do you know any definition of center for TROs?

Comment: I know very little about TROs, but it seems reasonable that there should be a good definition of center for them. My first guess would be $\{z: abz^*c = az^*bc$ for all $a,b,c\}$?

Comment: Oh, you can't do that, never mind. Not sure how a definition could go, then.

Comment: I searched in literature, I found the definition of commutativity Of TRO but I didn’t found the definition of center anywhere. In case you come up with something, please do comment on the question I have linked in above comment.

Comment: Okay. I'd think that really understanding the definition of commutativity should give some clues.

Comment: The definition of center which was suggested in the question I linked above in comment is motivated by definition of commutativity only. At first look, it seems like a good definition but as turned out that it doesn’t coincide with usual definition of commutativity for $C^{\ast}$-algebra. I can’t really think of any other definition for center as of now.